# First Order Differential Equation - Solution in the case of $y(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation:
$$y'=y\frac{y+2x-1}{x+y},$$
with solution
$$y^2+2xy-ce^{2x}=0.$$

It now asks for the solutions that satisfy $y(0)=0$. How do I solve this?

Comment: Sub in $y(0) = 0, x = 0 \rightarrow 0 + 0 - c = 0 \rightarrow c = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, only $y=-2x$ is a solution, as for $y=0$ the ODE does not make any sense.

Comment: $y(y+2x) = 0 \rightarrow y = 0, ~ y = -2x$

Comment: @Amzoti: Right!

Comment: @Amzoti the problem with the solution $y=0$ is that plugging it in to the differential equation gives you $0/0$ for every $x,y$ on the curve

Comment: I was merely showing that for the $-2x$ result.

Comment: I still don't understand how you obtain these solutions.

Comment: @Alejandro: Set $y(0)=0$ in $y^2+2xy-c\mathrm{e}^{2x}$, and obtain that $c=0$, and hence $y(y+2x)=0$. As $y$ is differentiable, either $y\equiv 0$ or $y\equiv -2x$. But $y=0$ is not acceptable.